# php mysql pdo - category and subcategory items for menu

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have 2 database tables, category and subcategory with following fields:

```
category table     -  category_id, category_name, status
subcategory table  -  subcategory_id, subcategory_name, category_id, status
```

The `subcategory.category_id` is related with `category.category_id`

I need to create a menu with category and subcategory items. Only those items are displayed `where category.status and subcategory.status = "Enabled".`

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM category C LEFT OUTER JOIN subcategory S
ON C.category_id = S.category_id AND S.status = 'Enabled'
WHERE C.status = 'Enabled'
```

For example:

Apparel:(category)

```
     Mens Wear (subcategory)

     Laddies Wear (subcategory
```

Mobile
(No subcategory)

I need to have all category displayed, irrespective of whether it has a subcategory or not. Only those with status "Enabled" in both tables need to be displayed.

**My issue is that:**

I get no category_id value for the second category which has no subcategory items, like following example:

1 Mens Wear

```
1 Jackets

2 Sweaters
```

Computers

For Mens wear category I have id of 1 and for subcategories jackets with subcategory id 1 and sweaters with subcategory id of 2.

No id for second category "Computers" with no subcategory items.

What is wrong with my sql statement? I am unable to understand.

**Issue Solved:**

This issue is due to the following:

If you do an OUTER LEFT JOIN and set PDO FetchALL to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, any primary key you used in the OUTER LEFT JOIN will be set to a blank if there are no records returned in the JOIN.

Fix:

The fix is to simply specify your field names in the SELECT clause instead of using the * as a wild card, or, you can also specify the field in addition to the *.

In my sql :
    SELECT DISTINCT *, C.category_id

Comment: `"Is my query correct for obtaining the output required?"` - Run the query and find out.  Do you get the expected output?  `"How can i proceed further"` - By continuing to develop your code?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why is category_id missing from the second category which has no subcategory ?? Is my sql query correct ? Or is it something to do with pdo? Mysql workbench gives rows including category_id and other values null.

Comment: "DISTINCT *" is pretty much meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Your left join won't return the unmatched values because you have `S.status = 'enabled'` term in there. If you want to return the 'category with no subcategory' items you should move this term to the 'where' portion and make it optional (IE 'and (s.status = enabled OR isnull( s.status))

Comment: It is returning the values correctly, except for category id of second category which has no subcategory..I have already tried :  WHERE C.status = 'Enabled' AND S.status = 'Enabled' OR S.status IS NULL     Then, if i disable all subcategories, category will not be displayed as condition not met (S.status is 'Enabled' OR S.category IS NULL ....Query done on Mysql workbench produces results with id correctly..in php it is not getting displayed correctly.

Comment: To do the comparison in the join you need to group them with (). `where c='' and (s = '' Or isnull(s))` Otherwise the comparisons are not accurate.

Comment: Could you provide an example. Please see the updated array output of print_r i just posted along with php code. The array is not displaying category_id for second category Computers with no subcategory. Mysql query run gives correct output with 3 rows, including category_id for all records on Mysql WorkBench.

Comment: Issue solved and fix updated in my answer...This was driving me nuts :)